# How to control "Prevent App Nap" being displayed in applications "Get Info"?

Tags: macos, cocoa

When I right click on my OSX application and select "Get Info", the "Prevent App Nap" option is not there. How does one control this in Xcode or programmatically? I certainly don't remember doing anything to remove it.

I could not find anything relevant in the Apple Docs or searching online beyond users asking why a particular application did not have "Prevent App Nap" as an option. So how does a developer control that?

Or does this mean that App Nap is already disabled?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure, but it might have something to do with the base SDK used to build the application. I can build my app with a base SDK of 10.5, and for that version of the app the "Prevent App Nap" checkbox appears in Get Info. If I build the same app with a base SDK of 10.10, the "Prevent App Nap" checkbox does not appear. This is only an observation, I have not found any Apple doc that says that is actually their policy.

I’ve noticed that some applications on my 10.10.3 system do not include the “Prevent App Nap” checkbox, and some do. I thought it might be related to manually adding the NSAppSleepDisabled setting to the application plist, but that does not seem to be the case. For example, Firefox.app 38.0.5 *does* show the Prevent App Nap checkbox, as well as iMovie.app, but iPhoto.app and ITunes.app do not.